# Python library for implementing SAML2 based service provider and identity provider?

Tags: python, saml

I am looking for a Python library which can be used to implement SAML2 based service provider and identity provider.  The core library should not depend on any particular web-framework. I am looking for something which is more feature complete and preferably easy to use. Also the library should have more permissive license (non-GPL). After searching I found few links, I have pasted it here:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/SAML

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 17):

You can also take a look on https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml

Is also open source and the toolkit contains 2 demos: A django application and a Flask application.

Right now only works on Python 2.X

**Edited 13/05/2015**: There is a python 3.X version (beta, I'm still testing it): https://github.com/pitbulk/python3-saml (thanks bgaifullin for contributing it)

**Edited 13/04/2016**: Python 3.X version is stable and tested.

Comment: I'd recommend accepting this answer, as the onelogin.com solution appears to be the current "best" solution available as of this writing ...

Comment: Can Onelogin's python-saml be used as IDP ?

Comment: As the general description section of the toolkit says:
"OneLogin's SAML Python toolkit lets you turn your Python application into a SP (Service Provider) that can connect to an IdP (Identity Provider)."
so no, only works as SP.

Comment: Does it support the IdP-initiated flow where the SP (our app) receives the samlp:Response from the IdP directly as a first interaction?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon Yes.

Comment: OneLogin has [an official Python3-supporting project](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml) now.

Answer (score 12):

The **pysaml2** project at launchpad is pretty active now. I think that you were sprinting on it at PyCon 2011. The **pysaml2** package is included in Python package index (PyPi) and installable with `easy_install` / `pip`. The docs can be found at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysaml2

There is a related project for Django which can be found at PyPi: [djangosaml2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangosaml2)

The other project, **python-saml2** on google code, seems to be a bit older and not so active.

I don't have any experience with the other ones.

I found another one: https://github.com/tachang/PySAML

The abbreviations **pysaml2**, **PySAML** and **python-saml2**, which refer to three different projects, are a bit confusing.

**Update: 2020 Sep 29 (on behalf of @Umognog, thx)**

- python-saml2 is OneLogins' implementation, details here https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml
- python3-saml supersedes python-saml2, details here: https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml

**Update: 2019 Apr 27** - Current status of the projects:

- PySAML - Not updated since 2009.
- pysaml2 - Is Python3 compatible and taken under the https://idpy.org/ project
- python-saml2 - Does not seem to exist on pypi. No references found

Comment: Almost 2 years later, and pysaml2 isn't certified to work with Python 3.x unfortunately.

Comment: works now, no other libs i see do this