# Django SSO with Microsoft ADFS

Tags: django, adfs

My question may be too broad or vague, but I cannot best describe it in any other way than I am doing it.

I have multiple Django applications. I have implemented SSO successfully for the same. All this things work. Now, I have been given a new task and its like this.

I have to integrate Microsoft ADFS authentication into my suite of applications and broaden the scope of current SSO.

My understanding of it is as, when I log into my laptop which is on corporate network (I assume this is how I have to put it) I also get logged into my django applications

I seriously have no idea of how this work as I have no experience with ADFS. Can anyone with experience of this explain it with a scenario of how it works so that I can understand it and think of a solution to it.

Comment: [`django-auth-adfs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-adfs)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I went through that. Can you explain something. See I log in to my laptop the whole authentication process through adfs happens successfully, now open my browser go to my application. Now at this point how do I identify the logged in user? Wouldn't this be the point of some action you know like reading some file that stores some info about user identity or something like that.

Comment: When you authenticate with ADFS, you get a SAML token back that contains the assertions about the user i.e. claims. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291068(v=vs.110).aspx for an .NET example which will get you some hints, For background, read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930603/best-way-to-integrate-adfs-2-0-authentication-in-a-django-application?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

if Django supports SAML based login, then you set it up to trust ADFS. ADFS will automatically take care of logging in using your logged in credentials to a domain joined machine inside the corporate network. If the user accessed externally, it would prompt for password or a certificate based auth (e.g. smartcard) to login the user.

Comment: So what I understand from your answer is that, if I have a machine that is on domain "abc.com" and when a user logs into this machine adfs will automatically log that user with same credentials into my web application(login credentials are same for machine and web application). Correct me if I am wrong.