# Python - Logging in to Site with SAML 2.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, saml, saml-2.0

I am struggle to find resources to help me with an issue I have.  I have a site secured with SAML 2.0.  Can someone point me to a resource(s) showing how to login to a site using SAML 2.0?  Most of the python modules out there seem to be in regards of implementing SAML 2, I just need to login to a site implementing SAML 2.0.

Thank you

J

Answer (score 6):

Python-saml can help you do that: https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml

There are a few other projects that I've found but none seem to be very well documented. And as a warning its still quite complicated. The demo-flask or demo-django apps in there will help out.

If anyone else has a better explanation of how it all works in detail I would like to see it, but the wiki page has been the most helpful so far: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0

Also, this question has been asked before here: [Python library for implementing SAML2 based service provider and identity provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056475/python-library-for-implementing-saml2-based-service-provider-and-identity-provid?rq=1).

The app logging them in is actually the service provider. The identity provider is the server you authenticate them with.

Comment: Documentation has been my biggest issue. It's like great a pypi entry, but documentation, not so much

Comment: Yea and I think the real issue is that saml is complex in general, so any documentation is going to be quite complex as well. Its not the kind of tasks you can abstract away into a module, but more manual identification work with the IDP. I'm hoping for updated docs on python-saml eventually but for now that seems to be the best one. But learning saml concepts will help you more I think than better python-saml docs.