# Integrating with Google SSO SAML

Tags: python, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, google-sso

I am trying to integrate Google SSO with an application. During the Google wizard to create the application it provides an SSO Url in the form of but I can't find much documentation about how to use that URL. Anyone has any example using Python or documentation about how to deal with the Google SSO Url?

[Setup Single Sign-On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBbGs.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Logging in to Site with SAML 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989567/python-logging-in-to-site-with-saml-2-0)

Comment: check out https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml